# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 - No runtime environment deployed in this server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have installed IBM Mobile First Server on a VM. As a part of Mobile First installation, I installed Application Center, IBM DB2 , WAS Liberty Core as well and Mobile First Studio on my local machine. I am able to view the Mobile First console on http://localhost:9083/console and providing the required credentials.I uploaded a war file by using the Server Configuration Tool. Restarted Application Server. Tried with different war files.

My issue is when I open my mobile first console I'm getting

> No runtime environment deployed in this server

Here you can find my messages.log and server.xml files https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftb3bb71wyuarrl/share.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the following:

```
 <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9083"
                  httpsPort="9446" host="*" >
```

But kept this:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value='"9443"'/>
```

And in the log, it mentions:

> [9/24/15 8:29:06:429 CDT] 0000005b
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I
>   Impossible to establish a REST connection to :
>   service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST

In your previous question on the same topic it was identified that you have some VM network problems with the ports 9080 and 9443. So, try changing "9443" to align with the actual HTTPS port you're using, 9446.

Comment: Thanks @Idan, Now I can able to see runtime environments on MF Console. But it was showing Applications (0) , Adapters (0) etc like that . The war file which I was uploaded having applications/Adapters  in that

Comment: No. There are no applications inside a war file. You must deploy them, the wlapp and the adapter files.

Comment: How can we deploy wlapp and adapters separately in Server Configuration Tool

Comment: You do not deploy wlapp and adapter files via the Configuration Tool. You need to load the MobileFirst Console at: http://your-server:your-port/worklightconsole and deploy the files there.

Comment: Sure @Idan , Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @Idan for disturbing you again . a small doubt - How can we test the application which are deployed on console. I didn't find any Preview option  on console.  As previously if we right click on project and click on "Open Mobile First Console" then the preview option will be appear. I mean I want to see the output on mobile simulator.

Comment: There is no preview in a remote server environment. Install your app on a device and test that it successfully connects to your server.

Comment: OK. Can we configure remote server in Mobile First Studio?

Comment: There is nothing to configure for the remote server in Studio other than tha IP address that is put in the application. Why do you not read the documentation?

Comment: So the process is - Everything(Project creation,deployment,testing) we need to do on MF Studio. Finally we need deploy this war file, wlapp and adapters on remote server and then add applications in Application center. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. And I will not reply to any more questions you ask here. **read the documentation that will teach you about the product**.