# how to add runtime in ibm mobilefirst 7.1 in remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

how to add runtime in ibm mobilefirst 7.1 in remote server ?

As of now I have remote server where already one runtime exist, I have deployed a .wlapp and .adapter file in console and I am testing this on a device and its working fine as mentioned in [IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 - No runtime environment deployed in this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764356/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-7-1-no-runtime-environment-deployed-in-this-server)

Question is how can i add(deploy) another runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have another MobileFirst project, you need to use the IBM Configuration Tool in order to deploy the second .war file. It's basically following the same steps you did for the first .war file, only deploying a different (.war) file...

You can also deploy manually: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_app_server.html